# Why the LAN connection still awake after shutdown the PC?

Tags: lan, connection, internet-connection, remote-connection

im new in this website, i want to explain the issue about my LAN connection; last day i turned off my PC by the start menu (not switched off from the Power PCI) and i saw the LAN1 modem's LED is still green! So i decided to watch out the connection by other pc, i used my laptop and checked my DHCP clients by modem and viewed the MAC addresses, strangely the PC MAC address was in the list! First i feard about a hacking tool or like that; so used the network watcher and wireshark to focus on data transferring, i turned off whole of my devices through wifi and the network and found out there was a valid connection between my shutdown PC and the modem router by LAN cable and the tranfer rate was 1 Mb/s! To almost 100 hosts! Uninstalled the windows and used the Kaspersky anti virus and tested again but still i have the issue and i can't understand why the LAN port not shutdown when i turned off my PC! I have some important data on my PC and after my work i should turn the hardware switch off everytime when i leaving my work room! Please guys help me through this problem and give me some advise and let me know whats the reason technically. Best regards.

Comment: 1 Mbps of _what exactly_? You said you had Wireshark running, so what kind of packets did it show?

Comment: @grawity thanks for your comment; i read about WOL , but its not this type of connection! I see almost 100 hosts are connected to my PC (contains MS DNSs); these protocols are in the process: Tinkerforge on TCP/IP , NTLM, ANCP, (a bunch of) BFD & ... . !!

Comment: Ok, and are they addressed from/to that computer, or are they broadcast, or are they from/to your _other_ computers? Could you perhaps post the .pcap file somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computers will often leave the Ethernet port active to allow for wake-on-lan.  This is a function of most modern computers to allow one to remotely power on a machine by sending it a special packet, though laptops will usually completely power off the ports when shut down and running on battery.  You can read more about it at Wikipedia's [Wake-on-LAN page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN).

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer! I read about this protocol on wikipedia (the link you suggested); but here i don't see any magic packets on wireshark report! I see almost 100 hosts are connected to my pc and here have a big bandwidth between 2 of them (IPs will change but i pinged them they are in Ukraine and just an adsl providers: 178.93.X.X), there's 1Mb/s down Stream, and 250KB/s Up stream! I think this is abnormal!!

Comment: @IranianGuy, the only thing I can think of that would be drawing that kind of bandwidth on a PC that is shut down is if the PC has some kind of remote management hardware.  This is normally something found on server class hardware.  For example HP has iLO, Dell has DRAC, and Intel has AMT.  These technologies allow a remote user to see and control the console of your machine.  If you think this might be a possibility (your wireshark report should give you some indication if it is), you should look into setting up a firewall to block the remote users.

Comment: thanks alot; I'm the Administrator of my own PC and i work at my home so there is an abnormal connection; I used Zone Alarm and blocked the Remote connections, Done.